# What is a "fast pack" setup for a tent?

Tags: backpacking, tents, terminology

Reading around forums and in products, I see descriptions and weights for a "fast pack" setup for tents.

What does this mean and what is it used for?

Comment: Never herd of the phrase so I can't provide an answer. But it brings an association. There are two strategies when packing a tent after use (consequenctly unpack it next time) 1. fold inner and outer separately 2. remove the poles and roll everything else together.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Fast pack" refers to setting up a tent with just the fly, tent poles, and usually a groundsheet. You leave the inner body behind. For example, [here are the fast pack instructions for the Big Agnes Fly Creek UL1 tent](https://www.bigagnes.com/resources/products/flycreek1setupinst08.pdf), which is designed for this setup.

Fast packing saves a significant amount of weight, but makes you more vulnerable to insects and cold.

A similar lightweight shelter option is to use a tarp and your trekking poles.

Comment: That link is broken. It now redirects to their home page.